# Replace string with wildcard in a .txt file with Python

Tags: python, windows-7, python-2.7

I'm still new to scripting and am not sure the best method to accomplish what I am trying to do. This will be the first python script I am trying to write. Please note, I am using **Python2.7** for this.

I want to write a batch file for a user with an argument given. This argument will be a path. This path will change everyday and be used to execute job tests. I want to invoke it with `Nightly.bat "build path"`

Here's what I want to accomplish:

**1. Batch file ensures the path exists with health check.

2. Batch file executes the python file with the given variable.

3. Python file finds a string in the testrun script with the build path, and will replace that path with the given variable.

4.Batch file executes the testrun selenium script.**

Here is the code Python Code:

test1.txt contents:

```
blah
This is a first string
```

nightly.py contents:

```
import sys
import shutil
import os
import re

tf = open('tmp', 'a+')
string = "This is "

with open('test1.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
            string = re.sub ('This is .*', 'This is a second string', string)

shutil.copy('test1.txt', 'tmp')
tf.write(string)
f.close()
tf.close()
```

after executing the nightly.py file, this is the tmp file contents:

```
blah
This is a first stringThis is a second String
```

I need to make it so `This is a first string` is replaced by `This is a second string`

In the end, the tmp file should have the following contents:

```
blah
This is a second string
```

Thanks for continuing to try.

```
*****************************
* Updated for Kirbyfan64sos *
*****************************
```

nightly.py contents:

```
import sys
import shutil
import os

tf = open('tmp', 'a+')
with open('test1.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line == 'This is*':
            line = 'This is a second string' 
        tf.write(line)
f.close()
tf.close()
shutil.copy('tmp', 'test1.txt')
os.remove('tmp')
```

Comment: I can't find a question.

Comment: Help with what specifically? Which part have you been running into issues/difficulties with?

Comment: The syntax in which to write the python file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer...

test1.txt before Nightly.py executed:

```
blah
blah
This is a first string
blah
blah
```

BTW tabs make a difference in the code with notepad++

```
import sys
import os
import re
import shutil

tf = open('tmp', 'a+')

with open('test1.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        build = re.sub ('This is.*','This is a second string',line)
        tf.write(build)
tf.close()
f.close()
shutil.copy('tmp', 'test1.txt')
os.remove('tmp')
```

test1.txt after Nightly.py executed:

```
blah
blah
This is a second string
blah
blah
```

Comment: Congratulations! Sorry I couldn't help too much. Had a little IDE trouble and forgot all about it.

Answer (score 1):

The code should look like:

```
import sys
tf = open('tmp', 'a+')
with open('WP8974_AudioDecode.html') as f:
    for line in f.readlines() do:
        if line == '<td>\\frosty\*</td>':
            line = '<td>\\frosty\' + sys.argv[1] + '</td>' 
        tf.write(line)
f.close()
shutil.copy('tmp', 'WP8974_AudioDecode.html')
os.remove('tmp')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try it. On the if line part, shouldn't it be 1 `=` since we are using a wildcard?

Comment: I get the following error ----- AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Thanks for the update on `.write`. The problem is this only works if the string is static (no wild card). If I use the wild card then it doesn't replace the string.

Comment: @FiddleFreak: I am trying to update it. See if you can get it. Check out the re module. Giving me some trouble. I am having some trouble. Will have you an answer soon. Sorry about the delay.

Comment: I have tried with the re.sub module. I still can't get it right. Updated the post for you on what I have so far...

Comment: @FiddleFreak: The lines are swapped around. The `shutil.copy` should be AFTER the `tf.write`. Also, it should be `shutil.copy('tmp', 'test1.txt')`.

Comment: Still isn't working. I got a lot of syntax errors until updating the code. But it still doesn't replace the line. Check latest updated on my post for what I am seeing.

Answer (score 0):

My method as follows, which operates on the file in question, without having to duplicate/copy files:

```
import re

with open('target_file.txt', 'r') as file: 
    filedata = file.read()

filedata = re.sub('This is.*', 'This is the second string', filedata)

with open('target_file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(filedata)
```